# Can I use Content Deployment feature in WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

I'm really newbie with SharePoint stuff.
So I've been asked to move the content of a SharePoint WSS 3.0 (no MOSS installed, only the free version) test site to a development MOSS 2007 site. I've looked around for Content deployment jobs and stuff and tested it out with the MOSS dev site to our MOSS prod site. It worked great.

But when I started to look for the deployment feature in the central admin of the WSS site, I cannot find it.

So my question is : when the dev WSS 3.0 was installed, did they forget an option, or WSS 3.0 do not have this feature at all ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphyboy,

Content Deployment is a MOSS-only feature; it is not present in WSS.  The PRIME API (upon which MOSS' content deployment functionality is constructed) is present in the WSS platform, so you could conceivably build your own version ... but that approach is seldom more efficient or cost-effective.

As Chris hinted at, you can still perform basic export (**STSADM -o export**) and import (**STSADM -o import**) operations via the command line, and these leverage the same functionality that is present in MOSS' Content Deployment's paths and jobs.  It's obviously more manual (and more work), but you could script these operations for a poor man's content deployment system if needed.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the content deployment wizard works on WSS sites but if it does then you could use that:

http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Deployments are done with [stsadm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261956.aspx)

Comment: Is there another way to do it ? Problem is, I do not have access to the server where WSS is installed.